# How to group Json data based on Month and plot it using google chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I am using google chart plugin to plot a area chart,by using JSON data as show below code, which contains value and a date by the chart should be printed based on month.

Link show in image 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5h82.png)

how to plot the chart based on month using google chart

is it possible to do it with google charts buit in features and need to write some customized javascript for that achive?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'value'],
        [
            "1/Jan/2017",
            28
        ],
        [
            "5/Feb/2019",
            174
        ],
        [
            "8/Mar/2017",
            150
        ],
        [
            "2/Apr/2019",
            174
        ],
        [
            "18/May/2019",
            100
        ],
        [
            "22/Jun/2019",
            5
        ],
        [
            "30/Jul/2019",
            178
        ],
        [
            "28/Aug/2019",
            59
        ],
        [
            "1/Sep/2019",
            87
        ],
        [
            "10/Oct/2019",
            50
        ],
        [
            "15/Nov/2019",
            123
        ],
        [
            "20/Dec/2019",
            108
        ]


    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Date',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#333'
            }
        },
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        pointSize: 5,
        dataOpacity: 0.5,
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0
        }

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to format the x-axis as a date,
need to convert the first column in the data table from a string to an actual date...

we can use a data view with a calculated column to convert the date...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([{
  type: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0));
  }
}, 1]);
```

also, since the data is not in order by date, we can convert the view back to a data table and sort it...

```
data = view.toDataTable();
data.sort([{column: 0}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'value'],
    [
      "1/Jan/2017",
      28
    ],
    [
      "5/Feb/2019",
      174
    ],
    [
      "8/Mar/2017",
      150
    ],
    [
      "2/Apr/2019",
      174
    ],
    [
      "18/May/2019",
      100
    ],
    [
      "22/Jun/2019",
      5
    ],
    [
      "30/Jul/2019",
      178
    ],
    [
      "28/Aug/2019",
      59
    ],
    [
      "1/Sep/2019",
      87
    ],
    [
      "10/Oct/2019",
      50
    ],
    [
      "15/Nov/2019",
      123
    ],
    [
      "20/Dec/2019",
      108
    ]
  ]);
    

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    type: 'date',
    label: 'Date',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0));
    }
  }, 1]);
  data = view.toDataTable();
  data.sort([{column: 0}]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {bottom: 56},
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {format: 'MMM', title: 'Date',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'} },
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom'},
    pointSize: 5,
    dataOpacity: 0.5,
    vAxis: {minValue: 0}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping WhiteHat, But it adds the datas based on month, it should not add the datas of same month only for plotting it needs grouping by month, actully it should plot the every data seperately eg, if Jan month has two datas means it should plot both the datas should not add the data and plot.

Comment: is there any posibilities that i can show the date if the data is for one month and if the data is more than one month means then we can show the month?

Comment: yes, it's possible by providing your own `hAxis.ticks` -- would you be willing to enter another question?

Comment: Thanks for the help and tips, i am newbie to javascript and js libraries that is why i was suppose to ask more questions, I have tried that hAxis.ticks already if it is fixed number of datas mean we can Thnaks for the help wspecify the particular tick number, but my data will be dynamic. in that hAxis.ticks will not work right, is there any other way it can take the dynamic legends and show instead if we mention the numbe of legends?

Comment: `ticks` will work, and dynamically. happy to show you, just would like to get credit for another question.