# Multiple data points per date in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I am using a standard php array that pulls data from a database in reverse order to create a Google Chart. Something like this...

```
$graph_data = array(array('Date', 'Amount'));
foreach (array_reverse($transactions) as $transaction) 
{ 
    array_push($graph_data, array(date("d M", strtotime(substr($transaction->createdOn, 0, 10))), $transaction->balanceAfter + 0));
    }
```

Works fine.

This process creates a new data point on the chart for each row of the array. The problem I have is when there are multiple events ($transaction) on a date. Each event is plotted as a new chart point, whereas I would like to graph the last data point for each date. (constant time series)

What is the best way to go about this?

Is there a simple google chart setting to use the last data point per date? I have searched but found nothing on this.

Thanks

Comment: Sure,

This is the array output. As you can see there are many points on the same date. Each show as a new point on a graph, despite sharing the same date

0: (2) ["Date", "Amount"]
....
10: (2) ["09 Jan", 13]
11: (2) ["29 Jan", 11]
12: (2) ["29 Jan", 9]
13: (2) ["29 Jan", 4]
14: (2) ["29 Jan", -3]
15: (2) ["29 Jan", 0]
16: (2) ["29 Jan", -3]
17: (2) ["30 Jan", -5]
18: (2) ["30 Jan", 0]
19: (2) ["30 Jan", -1]
20: (2) ["30 Jan", -2]
21: (2) ["30 Jan", -3]
22: (2) ["30 Jan", -4]
23: (2) ["30 Jan", -5]
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use the [`group()` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group),
with a custom aggregation function,
to only display the last point for a given date.

```
var dataLast = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,  // data table
  [0],   // group by column
  [{     // aggregated column
    column: 1,
    type: 'number',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
    // aggregation function
    aggregation: function (values) {
      // return the last value for the group
      return values[values.length - 1];
    }
  }]
);
```

the aggregation property above,
should be a function that accepts a single argument,
that is an array of the values for each group.

in this case, we just return the last value in the array.

the group method returns a data table,
which we can use to draw the chart.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Amount'],
    ['09 Jan', 13],
    ['29 Jan', 11],
    ['29 Jan', 9],
    ['29 Jan', 4],
    ['29 Jan', -3],
    ['29 Jan', 0],
    ['29 Jan', -3],
    ['30 Jan', -5],
    ['30 Jan', 0],
    ['30 Jan', -1],
    ['30 Jan', -2],
    ['30 Jan', -3],
    ['30 Jan', -4],
    ['30 Jan', -5]
  ]);

  var dataLast = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,  // data table
    [0],   // group by column
    [{     // aggregated column
      column: 1,
      type: 'number',
      label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
      // aggregation function
      aggregation: function (values) {
        // return the last value for the group
        return values[values.length - 1];
      }
    }]
  );

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataLast);  // use grouped data to draw the chart
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. This was exactly what I was looking for. 

The only issue I am finding is that is it putting the seventh row (Oct 2018 date) as the last in the chart, after today's date.

The 'data' array is being processed in the correct order, but the group method is not processing the first 6 rows and re-ordering the 7th row.

Comment: EDIT: The issue is the date order of the grouped array. I haven't worked out the formula, but it is not chronological.

eg Nov18 - Feb19 - Jan19 - Jun18 - Jan19 - Oct18.

I changed the data array to include years as I noticed initially it was out of sequence and assumed it was putting Oct after Jan, however this didn't fix it.

Thanks

Comment: yes, I didn't notice with the sample data, the group function will automatically sort. and since the values are strings and not actual dates, they get out of order. the best solution would be to use actual dates, otherwise, year will need to be first, followed by the month number, instead of name...

Comment: I tried using a ISO 8601 date format, which worked except that I couldn't format the chart axes. It just inserted the ISO format.

I also tried inserting another column with for the chart format and one for the date order, but the group method strips it down and keeps the ISO format, despite being the 3rd column.

When you say 'actual dates' what format are you suggesting for the data array? Currently I am using php's strtotime() function in Y-m-d format.

Thanks

Comment: if strings, format option is not available -- using actual dates is the way to go, but it will require hefty changes, here is a [php example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) -- you can try using 3rd column, but will need to add it to the "group by columns" in the group method --> `[0, 2]`

Comment: or you can try converting the iso date to an actual date using a data view on the client, before grouping. [here is an similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51483064/5090771)...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. Needs some time to work through these options but pretty much there. Cheers

Comment: Hey @WhiteHat - quick followup on this. I am having trouble finding the number of rows (length) in the aggregated dataset (dataLast in this example). How can i do this as keep on getting undefined? Thanks

Comment: use --> `dataLast.getNumberOfRows()`

Comment: Legend! Thanks again